# Add custom information box in Magento admin and email in Invoice and Order

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

After a user places a new order, their record is saved in a new table against order incremental ID.

Now I want to show this record in invoice and order email in the another box, like in screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity this is code related question of magento. If you really know about magento so answer this question properly. thank you

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I have searched for this but I dont know how to add this box in invoice and order. so i need steps from the start..

Comment: @SeffconSolutions - Please, then, post the code in question and then ask a question about that code. Asking a question that could be answered with code is **not a programming-related question** - it would be a **programming-related answer**. The question must be about coding.

Comment: @Enigmativity Really? :D

Comment: @SeffconSolutions - Yes, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Have added below code in

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/Info.phtml

```
<?php 
        $collection = Mage::getModel('parentorderreport/parentorderreport')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.order_id', array('eq' => $_order->getRealOrderId()));

        if(count($collection->getItems()))
        {
            ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="box-left">
                    <!--Payment Method-->
                    <div class="entry-edit">
                        <div class="entry-edit-head">
                            <h4 class="icon-head head-payment-method"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Parent Child Information') ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div>
                                <strong>Student Name:</strong>
                                <?=$collection->getFirstItem()->getChildName()?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <strong>Grade:</strong>
                                <?=$collection->getFirstItem()->getGrade()?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <strong>Classroom:</strong>
                                <?=$collection->getFirstItem()->getClassroom()?>
                            </div>
                            <?php 
                            // print_r($collection->getItems()); 
                             ?>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php
        }
     ?>        </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php
        }
     ?>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXAM5.png)